# Show Bootstrap Popover on Blur not click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, blur

This seems like a pretty simple thing, but I am pulling my hairs on it for hours now: I want to check for uniqueness of usernames on a signup form. So I am writing a small AJAX jquery function that calls some endpoint, while I show a popover that the uniqueness is being checked.

https://jsfiddle.net/7p41z88h/

This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:200px">
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" name='name' id="username" >
    </div>
  </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js:

```
var check = '<img src="http://investors.boozallen.com/assets_files/spinner.gif" /> Checking if this username is available...';

$('#username').blur( function(){
    $("#username").popover( { 
        title: '', 
        content: check, 
        html:true, 
        placement: 'top' 
    });
});
```

My expectation would be that this shows the `popover` on the `blur` event, but it shows it after I click somewhere and back into the input. Why? What am I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create popover first, then show it on blur.

```
var check = '<img src="http://investors.boozallen.com/assets_files/spinner.gif"> Checking if this username is available...';

$('#username').blur(function() {
  $(this).popover({ 
    title: '', 
    content: check, 
    html: true, 
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'manual'
  });
  $(this).popover('show');
});

$('#username').click(function() {
  $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/GqrkyB)

Comment: There is still a weird behavior though: type something into the input, click a few times on input till the popover disappears and now the popover toggles on `click` and on `blur` - how do I detach the click event?

Comment: Actually I found better solution, check it now.